# Need help to Create Button Group with Pointer Shape

Tags: html, css

[image]

I wanted to create this button group.

```html
<div class="btngroup">
  <button type="button" class="btn">Organization</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn">Project</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn">Applications</button>
</div>
```

The hover effect is like the grey color in the 'Application'

Comment: Those don't look like buttons. More like a breadcrumb.

Comment: Yes, Look likes breadcrumbs. But I need to do them using buttons.

Comment: Why buttons specifically, and not simple links?

Comment: There are other functionalities going inside this look. Haven't put it all here.

Comment: Even these styles with links are fine. I can rearrange it to the buttons. Hard to create those rounded corners with triangle. thats where I'm stuck right now.

Comment: Please could you describe exactly what your question is? And include any relevant CSS.

Comment: What exactly I need is to create the design I put using html and CSS.

Comment: I think using an SVG for the triangles would be the best way to go here honestly. slapping it on there with some padding to cover the element when it's absolutely positioned and then you are good to go.

Comment: Please show us the CSS you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please check the below code link? Hope it will work for you. We have made a structure using the flex-box property.

Please refer to this link: https://jsfiddle.net/yudizsolutions/oa8pyjuq/

```css
.btngroup {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid #eeeeee;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 10px;
  max-width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.btngroup .btn {
  position: relative;
  border: 0;
  background: transparent;
  color: #b2b2b2;
  padding: 20px 40px 20px 50px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 300;
  flex: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.5s;
}

.btngroup .btn::after,
.btngroup .btn::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
}

.btngroup .btn.active::after,
.btngroup .btn:hover::after {
  background-color: #fbfbfb;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: -4px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.btngroup .btn::before {
  top: 50%;
  right: -15px;
  height: 44px;
  width: 44px;
  border: 1px solid #eeeeee;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgb(255 255 255 / 0%) 0%, rgb(255 255 255) 10%);
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.btngroup .btn.active::before,
.btngroup .btn:hover::before {
  background: #fbfbfb;
}
```

```html
<div class="btngroup">
  <button type="button" class="btn">Organization</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn">Project</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn">Applications</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, @Yudiz Solutions. This should be working for me. Will Make adjustments and use this.